# What's better when RSA-encrypting an AES passphrase: more data or better padding?

Tags: openssl, aes, rsa

An application encrypts data with AES (`aes-256-cbc`) using a key and IV derived from a randomly-generated *pass-phrase* (`openssl enc -pass...`). It encrypts the pass-phrase with 2048-bit RSA. So the pass phrase data is limited by the size of the RSA key (i.e to a maximum of 256 bytes) and any *padding* scheme

Given the random characteristic of the pass-phrase data (e.g. `openssl rand`), which is better: more data or better padding ?

Example pass phrase lengths:

- 256 bytes with no padding (pass `-raw` option to `openssl rsautl`)
- 245 bytes with the OpenSSL default `pkcs` padding
- 214 bytes with `oaep` padding (using the default SHA1 digest)
- 190 bytes with `oaep` padding using a SHA256 digest

To paraphrase, if the random source is good enough is there anything to gain from using fewer random bits for the key and then applying a padding scheme and, if so, which padding scheme is best ?

Comment: Any more than 32 bytes of random key is a total and complete waste of effort. However, `rand` can produce all 256 8-bit values but trying to pass those through a shell to a process like `openssl enc` usually loses at least some of them, which changes the derived key and your decryption doesn't work. You should either generate a _password_ of _characters_ (not bytes) with 256 bits entropy and allow `openssl enc` to use its (poor) PBKDF, or generate a _key_ and IV (max 48 bytes), convert to hex and use `-K` (uppercase) and `-iv`. Or if your keys are single use you _can_ use fixed IV like zero.

Comment: It isn't a key though, it's a password. Are you suggesting having a random *password* of more than 32 bytes is pointless? Admittedly, if the password is comprised of bytes then care does have to be taken when passing it - don't assign to a shell variable - or restrict to characters as you say.

Comment: A _key_ for AES (and most symmetric algorithms) can be any combination of bits and 256 bits is enough, which is 32 bytes on pretty much all systems of interest today (although there are some exceptions, which I didn't note due to comment limits). But shells and the openssl program both can't handle aribtrary bits, hence you need workarounds, and the one used here is hex (so 32 bytes is 64 hexits=characters, but still 256 bits of entropy). ...

Comment: ... A _password_ is characters that at least notionally a human can type, _and_ in this situation a shell can pass to openssl, and that are _derived_ to produce the key, which is _different from the password_; this is always less dense and often significantly less so than the all-bits case, but how much depends on details of your systems and some choices you make. One fairly easy choice nowadays is a 64-character set so that 43 independent uniform characters is enough (slightly over 256 bits of entropy); there are lots of other choices.